# array_map with unlink, using a wild card not working

Tags: php

Here's what I currently have:

`$pic_path` provides a path like so: `path/to/img`

`$toid` is a number, and like `pic_path`, no slash before or after.

```
$file_path = glob( $pic_path . "/" . $toid . ".*" );
array_map('unlink', $file_path);
```

The picture I am trying to delete is indeed in the specified path.

I've tried using:

```
$file_path = glob( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/" . $pic_path . "/" . $toid . ".*" );
array_map('unlink', $file_path);
```

Also tried:

```
$file_path = glob($pic_path . "/" . $toid . ".*");
array_walk($file_path, function ($file) {
    unlink($file);
});
```

and I've also tried replacing the * wild card for the actual image extension.

Any idea?

Comment: What exactly is the question here? Also, `array_walk` seems a better fit than `array_map`

Comment: Phil, isn't stating my problem just enough to understand that I need help about it...

Comment: You haven't stated any problem. If I had to *guess*, I'd say the files you were expecting to be deleted are not being deleted. But again, that's just a *guess*

Comment: So what does `var_dump($file_path)` say?

Comment: In your `array_walk` closure, add `echo realpath($file);` and see if the path is indeed correct

Comment: I see you used array_walk but have you tried foreach on the resulting glob array?

Comment: Phil, the problem is also in the main title, but I understand your point and agree that I could be clearer.

Comment: Yeah... permissions...